# Do we have to create a json schema for each type of json object we may have?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am working on an email service project which accepts a json object with the data that would go into the email template.

I am planning on defining a json schema for the json objects that would be generated for each email type. I have 30 different types of email templates.

Do I need 30 different schemas defined? Or can I consolidate all in one schema and generate json object as required referencing the schema?

Can someone please give me their inputs or provide me with a reference guide that would clear my doubts?

Comment: Hard to discuss what may be best approach on schema without tangible examples of what actually differs between these 30 different template types.

Comment: they are pretty different from each other. few deal with the online orders, few are user account specific, few are shipment related etc.

Comment: @Madi you should try to make a small example of what you want to achieve. If you want to restrict all possible mails to those 30types, you would probably want a single schema root, and make use of oneOf/anyOf keywords to describe the allowed schemas. See http://json-schema.org/example2.html